# SQL server, view available columns of a link object

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I have a link server object created on my SQL Server, this link has lots of objects in there.

To get data from it, I use openquery:

```
select * from openquery(LinkName, 'select * from tableorview')
```

my question is, is there a way i can get the available columns from tableorview that is in the linked object?

Update:  The server my DB is SQL Server, I am linking to teradata

thanks

Comment: Since you have a linked server why not simply query sys.columns? Select * from LinkServer.DatabaseName.sys.columns

Comment: "[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Table qualifiers not supported by data source".  i guess the server i'm linking to is teradata

Answer (score 0):

ended up using this.

```
select * from openquery(linkedname, 'SELECT DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName
FROM dbc.ColumnsV
WHERE ColumnName LIKE ''%colname you need%''')
```

Founded on another thread but closed by accident, can't find it to pose.